# Automatic authentication when connected to Wi-Fi

Tags: python, wifi, single-sign-on

I'm working on a project where I want any user connected to my Wi-Fi network to be automatically authenticated to an eternal website. So, when the user will try to connect himself to the website, he/she sill see himself automatically logged in.
I had as Idea to build up a mechanism that could authenticate the users of the local network to the external site. The idea is to put in place a server that will be between the inner network and the AP. The server will listen the inner network and when a new user tries logs in, the server gets the Users IP, MAC and other information and then goes to the external site and logs in the user. I tried to use python requests and selenium to automate the connection but nothing still.
That's what I had in mind but I'll like to know which technologies to use and if this type of system already exists.

Comment: Can you describe what you have done so far, what your code looks like? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You can use mac-address of devices to differentiate the users and on server side u can check the ip of a user.